# Manipulating an installation process with powershell

Tags: powershell, executable

Is there any way in which powershell can "automatically" fill out the properties in a installer? I mean, powershell calls an executable and then based on the screen displayed fill out the options and hit next with code?

Thanks

Comment: I am flagging this question as off topic because this needs more details and clarity. We can't advance without knowing the name of installer.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic.  It's a valid "how can PowerShell help me with this scenario" type of question.

Comment: while this aint what i consider a valid Question at this site, the usual answer for this type of problem is to use a 3rd party util that is _designed_ for this type of thing. AutoHotKey and AutoIT both are designed for this - and the 2nd has a powershell module that is apparently well thot of. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the executable. For .msi files, you can use something like:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "<<whatever>>" -Wait -Passthru
```

For a proper list of examples and command line arguments, take a look at this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options?redirectedfrom=MSDN

For other types of executables, you could open cmd, cd to their path, and type the name of the executable. This should give you (for most executables) a brief help about their command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible, but could be very tedious.  Ideally, your installer would allow some command line arguments or a response file for the required responses.

But, if that's not possible, you might be able to accomplish it with `SendKeys`.  Here's an example of using `SendKeys` from PowerShell with COM and/or Win32 Interop: https://superuser.com/a/1250038/142958 that might get you started.